# How to reload page with specifing query string on IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I want to reload current page with a certain query string.
I'm trying the following code:

```
document.location.search = '?key=value';
```

It works very well on modern browsers (such as Firefox or Safari),
but it doesn't work on IE7.

I tried another code:

```
document.location.search = '?key=value';
document.location.reload(true);
```

But it reloads current page *without* query string and it is not what I want.

How to reload page with specifing query string on IE7?

*UPDATE*: I'm sorry this is not issue about document.location.search. The cause of problem is missing of 'return false' on 'onclick' attribute. Thank you for all those who give me advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `document.location.replace(URL)` You'll have to supply the full new URL.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this on my mac, but does this work?

```
location = '?key=value';
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It is not the cause of problem. See update on original post. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason you can't set the window location directly?

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + '?key=value';
```

keep in mind you may want to add some conditional logic to append `&` instead of `?` if the URL already contains a querystring.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. See update on original post. Sorry!